# Sidekiq: Get config

Tags: config, sidekiq

Is there any way to access the config for Sidekiq, inside a running server. For example, how to determine the `concurrency` setting? It would be useful for setting other values such as pool sizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Sidekiq.options[:concurrency]` will work.